# Take the latest year value for nested object

Tags: r

I have a nested object whereby the name of individual vehicles in the inner nest. This is not my dataset but I can reproduce the error with `mtcars`. Essentially, I am trying to grab the `manufacturing_size` for the latest year when its anything but `Not Provided`, and use only this value for `manufacturing_size`. However, for whatever reason the map/function does not enter all nests.

dataset:

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column()
emp <- c("Not Provided","Less than 250","250 to 499","500 to 999","1000 to 4999","5000 to 19,999")
mtcars$manufacturing_size <- c(rep(emp, 5) , "Not Provided", "Less than 250")
mtcars$year <- rep(2018:2021, 8)


mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars3 <- mtcars

mtcars1$year <- rep(c(2019:2021, 2018), 8)
mtcars2$year <- rep(c(2020:2021, 2018, 2019), 8)
mtcars3$year <- rep(c(2021:2018), 8)

mtcarsAll <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars1, mtcars2, mtcars3)
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
mtcars %>% nest_by(gear) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% nest(data=rowname) %>%
                                                                                      mutate(data = map(data, function(x){
  someSize <- x[x$year == x[which.max(x$year),]$year,]$manufacturing_size
  if(someSize != 'Not Provided'){
    x$manufacturing_size = someSize
    return(x)
    
  }else {
    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
      if(x$year[i] != 2018){
        someSize <- x[x$year == x[which.max(x$year)-i,]$year,]$manufacturing_size
        if(someSize != 'Not Provided'){
          x$manufacturing_size = someSize
          return(x)
        }
      } else{
        someSize <- x[x$year == x[which.max(x$year)+i,]$year,]$manufacturing_size
        if(someSize != 'Not Provided'){
          x$manufacturing_size = someSize
          return(x)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
))))
```

Which produces the following error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `data = map(...)`.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `data = map(...)`.
Caused by error in `vectbl_as_row_location()`:
! Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
ℹ Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
✖ Input has size 1 but subscript `x$year == x[which.max(x$year)]$year` has size 0.
```

This is because If I remove most of the function and print out `someSize` then It enters the first outer nest but not the others. What is an easier alternative?

Using the answer below, the following works:

```
mtr <- mtcarsAll %>% group_by(rowname) %>%
  mutate(
    man_size = case_when(
      manufacturing_size != "Not Provided" & max(year) == year~ manufacturing_size
    )
  ) 

mtr %>% ungroup %>% 
    fill(man_size, .direction = "updown")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want. There is a lot of nesting in your example, which unless I am mistaken, isn't necessary.

I've altered your setup a little bit cause I don't think what you wanted was going to work:

- used `mtcars2` so as to not overwrite `mtcars`,
- replace `rep(emp, 5)` with random draws from a standard normal distrubution `rnorm(30)`) becuase you didn't define `emp`
- added a new grouping variable `group` so that each `year` only appears once for each group. (The way you had it with `gear` as the grouping var didn't work because there were multiple values for the most recent year)

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("make")
mtcars2$manufacturing_size <- c(rnorm(30),"Not Provided", "Less than 250")
mtcars2$group <- rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 4)
mtcars2$year <- rep(2018:2021, 8)
```

Then, rather than all the complex nesting you've done, you just do use an if_else statement or, I've prefered `case_when` to get the values you are intereseted in for the new variable `man_size`.

```
mtcars2 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    man_size = case_when(
      manufacturing_size != "Not Provided" & max(year) == year ~ manufacturing_size,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 32 × 16
# Groups:   group [8]
   make                mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb manufacturing_size group  year man_size        
   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <chr> <int> <chr>           
 1 Mazda RX4          21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 -0.10777645987017  A      2018 NA              
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 0.685034939673918  A      2019 NA              
 3 Datsun 710         22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 0.0216291773402855 A      2020 NA              
 4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 0.227610843395319  A      2021 0.2276108433953…
 5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 0.342964251360947  B      2018 NA              
 6 Valiant            18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1 1.20792448510301   B      2019 NA              
 7 Duster 360         14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4 0.395983818669596  B      2020 NA              
 8 Merc 240D          24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2 -0.42502805147035  B      2021 -0.425028051470…
 9 Merc 230           22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2 0.961054295375392  C      2018 NA              
10 Merc 280           19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4 -1.32030765978216  C      2019 NA              
# … with 22 more rows
```

If you then want to fill in those `NAs` with what you need you can just use `tidyr::fill`

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** after change from OP in comments.

OK, I see what you want now. Thanks for providing `emp`. I still made one more tiny change to your setup, to ensure there was a case where `Not Provided` would be the value of `manufacuring_size` for the maximum year in one of the groups (for group H).

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column()
emp <- c("Not Provided","Less than 250","250 to 499","500 to 999","1000 to 4999","5000 to 19,999")
mtcars2$manufacturing_size <- c(rep(emp, 5) ,  "Less than 250", "Not Provided")
mtcars2$group <- rep(LETTERS[1:8], each = 4)
mtcars2$year <- rep(2018:2021, 8)
```

We can then use the following:

```
mtcars3 <- mtcars2 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(
    man_size = case_when(
      max(year[manufacturing_size != "Not Provided"]) == year ~ manufacturing_size,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

Then if you want to fill in all the values, you can do:

```
mtcars3 %>% 
  fill(man_size, .direction = "updown")
```

Comment: I have updated the post to include `emp` this is somewhat helpful and I will see where I can take this approach to solving my problem. However, `group` should have the same value applied for `max`, but the max year may be `Not Provided` for manufacturing size, therefore we pick the year before it. It looks simple enough with your approach though so thnaks!

Comment: Ok, I think I've answered it for you now. Please accept that answer if it's what you are after! Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my code above to show how your update does not work, this is the closest representation of my actual dataset. We still get `Not Provided` because if `max(year)` is `Not Provided` then it uses this.

Comment: The problem is that your new dataset doesn't match the grouping variables, You need to group_by() all variables so that there isn't multiple years in each group. When  you do that it will work.

Comment: That is fine because we just group by `manufacturing_size`, I managed to get the solution I am after using your approach. Great approach BTW! would have never thought it. I will use a similar approach more often.

Comment: Oh ok, good news! Please accept the answer then if you can :).